# joint three tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables employee, promotion and punishment
Employee’s table structure something like this

```
Id       int
Fullname     varchar
...............
promotionDate       date
```

Promotion’s table structure is like this
    id                   int
    emp_id               int
    directorateDate      date

And punishment’s table structure is like this

```
id                  int
emp_id              int
direcotorateDate    date
```

Let’s say employee table has 200 records, each month a group of employees have promotion (after serving one year), I want to get the list of all employees in the current month that get promotion
I can easily get the list by this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE MONTH(promotionDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
   AND YEAR(promotionDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

My question is 
I want to count number of punishments and promotions  each employee got in the current year  from punishment and promotion table respectively 
I did this query but it did not get right results

```
SELECT e.fullname , COUNT(punish.emp_id) as siza ,COUNT(pro.emp_id) as supas
  FROM emp_employee as e
  LEFT JOIN emp_punishment as punish on punish.emp_id=e.id
  LEFT JOIN emp_promotion as pro on e.id=pro.emp_id
 WHERE ((MONTH(e.promotionDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
   AND YEAR(e.promotionDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))
   AND ( YEAR(punish.directorate_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) )
   AND ( YEAR(pro.directorate_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) )
 GROUP BY e.fullname;
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By joining directly the 3 tables you get duplicate rows.
`Group by emp_id` and aggregate separately each of the tables `emp_punishment` and `emp_promotion` and join the results to the table `emp_employee`.

```
select e.fullname, coalesce(pu.siza, 0) siza, coalesce(pr.supas, 0) supas
from emp_employee as e 
left join (
  select emp_id, count(*) siza
  from emp_punishment
  where year(directorate_date) = year(CURRENT_DATE)
  group by emp_id
) pu on pu.emp_id = e.id
left join (
  select emp_id, count(*) supas
  from emp_promotion
  where year(directorate_date) = year(CURRENT_DATE)
  group by emp_id
) pr on pr.emp_id = e.id
```

I used only the condition:

```
where year(directorate_date) = year(CURRENT_DATE())
```

because in your question you say:
*I want to count number of punishments and promotions each employee got in* **the current year** *from punishment and promotion*

Answer (score 0):

Removing `MONTH()` function, and moving each condition to their respective place, instead of within the `WHERE` clause should resolve the issue (Since, they're considered as if `INNER JOIN`s with the current style ).

Only keep common column `e.promotionDate` within the `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT e.fullname,
       COUNT(punish.emp_id) as siza ,
       COUNT(pro.emp_id) as supas
  FROM emp_employee as e
  LEFT JOIN emp_punishment as punish 
    ON punish.emp_id=e.id
   AND  YEAR(punish.directorate_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
  LEFT JOIN emp_promotion as pro 
    ON e.id=pro.emp_id
   AND YEAR(pro.directorate_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))
 WHERE YEAR(e.promotionDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
 GROUP BY e.fullname;
```